# comparison strings which have escape sequences

Tags: macos, shell, configure, ls

In many cases, `./configure` checks validity of `ls -t`.

My environment, OS X 10.11.6 zsh, returns the failure that says

'*configure: error: ls -t appears to fail.  Make sure there is not a broken
alias in your environment
configure: error: newly created file is older than distributed files!
Check your system clock*'

However, `ls -t` indeed works well.

It appears the output from `ls -t` causes the problem.
The output contains escape sequences for coloring.
In fact, if I `unset CLICOLOR` then the check of `ls -t` has no problems.

The problem exists in `test "$*" == "X conftest.file $srcdir/configure"` where "$*" has the escape sequences unless `unset CLICOLOR`.

Are there any ways to compare strings, where

'^[[31mMakefile.am^[[39;49m^[[0m' == 'Makefile.am' returns true.

otherwise I should make that by myself.???

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `(unset CLICOLOR; ./configure)` which temporarily unsets `CLICOLOR` so that the configure doesn't break?  The shell won't treat the two strings as equal; the characters in them aren't the same.  If you want to program a shell to do that comparison then … well, I suppose it would be fine, but a tad eccentric, and you'd have to work hard to get it used when needed (probably by installing it as `/bin/sh`, the ramifications of which don't bear thinking about if you have a mistake in the shell anywhere).

Comment: ```(unset CLICOLOR; ./configure)``` works. I couldn't come to it...  Thank you very much.